# App is hung on loading data on WKWebView() with strange error stack trace

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am loading data on WebView on my iOS App but my app is getting frozen. It is not crashing but freezing the app with the below stack trace. I don't have any idea where is issue actually. It is giving something related to ABBI SDK. I haven't used any such SDK in my app. As soon as I am calling the following method, I am getting this error.

```
self?.webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
```

Here is the console output

```
ABBI_SDK| ABEventsMgr.m:457 -[ABEventsMgr sendException:] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203fbbb4 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff2019ebe7 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203fba92 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   WebKit                              0x00007fff29644cb5 _ZN6WebKit28CompletionHandlerCallCheckerD2Ev + 127
    4   WebKit                              0x00007fff29760538 _ZN3WTF3RefIN6WebKit28CompletionHandlerCallCheckerENS_12RawPtrTraitsIS2_EEED2Ev + 48
    5   WebKit                              0x00007fff297f0abc _ZZN3WTF8BlockPtrIFv24WKNavigationActionPolicyEE12fromCallableIZN6WebKit15NavigationState16NavigationClient31decidePolicyForNavigationActionERNS5_12WebPageProxyEONS_3RefIN3API16NavigationActionENS_12RawPtrTraitsISC_EEEEONSA_INS5_27WebFramePolicyListenerProxyENSD_ISH_EEEEPNSB_6ObjectEE4$_10EES3_T_ENUlPKvE_8__invokeESQ_ + 70
    6   libsystem_blocks.dylib              0x00007fff2008a434 _Block_release + 130
    7   WebKit                              0x00007fff297e7eb8 _ZN6WebKit15NavigationState16NavigationClient31decidePolicyForNavigationActionERNS_12WebPageProxyEON3WTF3RefIN3API16NavigationActionENS4_12RawPtrTraitsIS7_EEEEONS5_INS_27WebFramePolicyListenerProxyENS8_ISC_EEEEPNS6_6ObjectE + 944
    8   WebKit                              0x00007fff298c4749 _ZN6WebKit12WebPageProxy31decidePolicyForNavigationActionEON3WTF3RefINS_15WebProcessProxyENS1_12RawPtrTraitsIS3_EEEERNS_13WebFrameProxyEONS_13FrameInfoDataEyONS_20NavigationActionDataESB_NSt3__18optionalINS1_16ObjectIdentifierINS_26WebPageProxyIdentifierTypeEEEEERKN7WebCore15ResourceRequestEOSL_ON3IPC17FormDataReferenceEONSK_16ResourceResponseERKNS_8UserDataEONS2_INS0_20PolicyDecisionSenderENS4_ISX_EEEE + 6337
    9   WebKit                              0x00007fff298c2e47 _ZN6WebKit12WebPageProxy42decidePolicyForNavigationActionAsyncSharedEON3WTF3RefINS_15WebProcessProxyENS1_12RawPtrTraitsIS3_EEEENS1_16ObjectIdentifierIN7WebCore18PageIdentifierTypeEEENS8_INS9_19FrameIdentifierTypeEEEONS_13FrameInfoDataENS9_21PolicyCheckIdentifierEyONS_20NavigationActionDataESF_NSt3__18optionalINS8_INS_26WebPageProxyIdentifierTypeEEEEERKNS9_15ResourceRequestEOSO_ON3IPC17FormDataReferenceEONS9_16ResourceResponseERKNS_8UserDataEy + 315
    10  WebKit                              0x00007fff298c2cec _ZN6WebKit12WebPageProxy36decidePolicyForNavigationActionAsyncEN3WTF16ObjectIdentifierIN7WebCore19FrameIdentifierTypeEEEONS_13FrameInfoDataENS3_21PolicyCheckIdentifierEyONS_20NavigationActionDataES7_NSt3__18optionalINS2_INS_26WebPageProxyIdentifierTypeEEEEERKNS3_15ResourceRequestEOSG_ON3IPC17FormDataReferenceEONS3_16ResourceResponseERKNS_8UserDataEy + 112
    11  WebKit                              0x00007fff29c049bf _ZN6WebKit12WebPageProxy17didReceiveMessageERN3IPC10ConnectionERNS1_7DecoderE + 12877
    12  WebKit                              0x00007fff29530f7d _ZN3IPC18MessageReceiverMap15dispatchMessageERNS_10ConnectionERNS_7DecoderE + 199
    13  WebKit                              0x00007fff29905d7b _ZN6WebKit15WebProcessProxy17didReceiveMessageERN3IPC10ConnectionERNS1_7DecoderE + 31
    14  WebKit                              0x00007fff2950d68e _ZN3IPC10Connection15dispatchMessageENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_7DecoderENS1_14default_deleteIS3_EEEE + 658
    15  WebKit                              0x00007fff2950ce66 _ZN3IPC10Connection24dispatchIncomingMessagesEv + 572
    16  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff334ff58f _ZN3WTF7RunLoop11performWorkEv + 303
    17  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3350057a _ZN3WTF7RunLoop11performWorkEPv + 26
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20369e25 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20369d1d __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 180
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203691f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20363951 __CFRunLoopRun + 875
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20363103 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2c851cd3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ffbe63 -[UIApplication _run] + 928
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff25000a53 UIApplicationMain + 101
    26  MyAPP                                0x00000001065c0e79 main + 809
    27  dyld                                0x000000010931ee1e start_sim + 10
    28  ???                                 0x000000010b23c51e 0x0 + 4481860894
)
2022-07-21 19:00:50.426834+0530 MyAPP[92824:1138257] ABBI_SDK| ABHTTPMgr.m:77 -[ABHTTPMgr doHTTPPostJSON:withArgs:completion:] POST request to server. URL https://stats.abbi.io/api/logs
```

Comment: It is likely coming from some 3rd party that you are using. It WebKit Apple's Webkit or some third party?

Comment: Webkit is a Apple's framework. Thing is that it is not showing any error message.

Comment: Yeah that isn't uncommon, it is just hidden, you can likely get more info from the API but if some 3rd party is using it you won't get info directly you have to submit a big with them, if you google ABBI it looks like one of from behavior/data collection APIs I would seriously consider removing whomever is putting that into your project. Remember that you/the publisher is responsible for everything that is done by the 3rd parties that you use your privacy policy has to reflect what they are doing.